# jQuery is not defined?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in the body of my page. (I know it would be better to load in the header, but I don't have access to the header.)

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert('hello world');
});
</script>
```

Firebug shows that `jquery-1.5.2.min.js` is loading fine, and it was `wget`ted straight from the jQuery downloads page, so there should be no issues with the content. However, the script barfs on `jQuery.noConflict()` with:

```
Error: jQuery is not defined
```

I've tried moving this line inside `(document).ready` but it doesn't help. So, how can I check that jQuery has loaded without referring to jQuery? :)

I need to use jQuery in noConflict mode as there are scriptaculous scripts on the same page.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked the content of the jquery-1.5.2.min.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the complete page it is tough to answer this one. However my best guess is that yes your jQuery libraries do (eventually) get downloaded, the next bit of script which fires and access jQuery object does so before jQuery scripts are ready. As a quick proof of concept can you try this simple (but very dirty hack) to see if I am on the right track?

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){alert(jQuery);},1000);
</script>
```

Comment: That produces the same error... I've given up and put it in the head (which I was hoping to avoid), thanks anyway!

Comment: Ahh no worries. I would have increased the timeout to say 4000 to see what happens!

Comment: Ok, still having problems even in the head. I upped the time to 4000 and I see an alert showing the following: `function (a, b) {
    return new d.fn.init(a, b, g);
}`. I'm also now getting a bunch of new prototype/scriptaculous script errors that weren't there before, I guess because I haven't called noConflict.

Comment: As another test could you modify your code to NOT include jQuery library and then have a simple alert(jQuery) at the end? It would be interesting to see if you get something alerted. That would mean, someething somewhere is defining the "jQuery" variable!

Comment: I put the <script> after everything else in the head including the CSS. That seemed to solve the problem... not sure why but will accept this answer anyway! thanks!

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice to know what was overriding jQuery variable though.

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out. I had `base href` set in the page, pointing at a different domain, and for some reason jQuery really didn't like that, even though it was loading the scripts ok - perhaps something to do with XSS?

Comment: Very interesting! But that won't explain why you had it working when you moved the <script> tag after everything in the header!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$.noConflict()`.  Make sure you import the jquery script after scriptaculous, and call noConflict before making any scriptaculous calls.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Nah, `jQuery.noConflict()` should work fine. `$` is just an alias to `jQuery`.